# Possible To put one button from jquery dialog to left?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have 3 buttons on one of my dialogs. I am wondering is there an easy way to move one of the buttons to the left(the delete button) as I think they are all too close together and could be accidentally clicked and if this can be done I think it would be better then a warning dialog.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set its style to:

```
float: left;
```

Comment: as a inline style? I only want this one button on this one dialog to have this. It generates the button for me so I don't even have an Id for it.

Comment: Well it's generated, but it might have some uniqueness to it that you can look at.  Use your favorite debugger and inspect the classes and IDs used on that modal/button.  I bet at least the modal has a unique identifier.  Then you simply add the CSS required: `#uniquemodalidthatyoufound .classusedonthebutton { float: left; }`.